# I tried to install Rails 4 gem y my CPanel and didnt work

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting

I have almost finished my first Ruby on Rails application, i have used Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.2.4.. then i want to deploy it, the hosting i took gave me 1month trial but they have installed CPanel 11 (it has rails 2.3.18 by default)

but when i try to install the rails 4.2.4 gem it gives me this:

```
>  Error installing rails:  i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

My questions are:

Is there a way to update the ruby?

Would i have any trouble if they just update to 1.9.3 when i have used 2.1.2?

[this is a screenshot from the gems in the cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lUpx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I had to upgrade my Ruby version to a higher one and I was in a very similar situation like yours. 
I used rvm for this. 
Use rvm for listing the ruby version with the following command:
rvm list known

Then upgrade ruby with: rvm install version_of_your_choice

Also, search the internet for tutorials. StackOverflow has all the answers.